# Editar texto en archivo con batch

Tags: windows, batch

Tengo que remplazar una línea dentro de un txt con batch y necesito ayuda con el código...
tengo los archivos prueba.txt y prueba2.txt
el objetivo es pasar del archivo 1 al 2 con el mismo contenido salvo que contenga una palabra especifica,en cuyo caso, se debe reemplazar la línea entera por una predefinida.

específicamente tengo problemas con el ' if ' y con la reasignación de la variable.

```
>@echo off

>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

>set p1=prueba.txt

>set p2=prueba2.txt


>for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%p1%) do (

>    set nl=%%a

>    if not "%n1%"=="%n1:texto=%" (

>        set n1=este texto esta mejor

>    )

>    echo !n1! >> %p2%

>)

>pause>nul

>exit
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este script debería funcionar:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set p1=prueba.txt
set p2=prueba2.txt

copy NUL %p2% 1>NUL 2>&1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%p1%) do (
  set n1=%%a
  if not "!n1!"=="!n1:texto=!" (
    set n1=este texto esta mejor
  )
  echo !n1! >> %p2%
)

pause>nul
exit
```

Lo que he corregido:

En algunos sitios referencias a "n1" y en otros "nl" (era una 'errata')

Dentro del bucle, deberías referenciar a la variable n1 como `!n1!` en lugar de `%n1%` esto es porque la estás actualizando dentro del bucle, pero en batch siempre recuperas el valor anterior a menos que utilices `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` y referencies a las variables con `!!`

Finalmente he agregado `copy NUL %p2% 1>NUL 2>&1` antes del for para vaciar el fichero de destino. Si no, en caso de que ejcutes el script varias veces, duplicarás el contenido de las líneas. Si no te interesa, puedes borrar esta línea.

Espero que te sirva.